# Java parses File.separator as %5c which isn't recognized as legit file path

Tags: java, string, selenium, file, upload

I'm not really sure when it started, but my Selenium framework stopped accepting path names with `File.separator`, I must use backslashes or I can't upload files.

If I type path like this:

```java
String DOCX = "uploads" + File.separator + "mock" + File.separator + "document_donotparse.docx";
```

I get such an error:

```
invalid argument: File not found : C:\XXX\Arbeit\tests\build\resources\test\uploads%5cmock%5cdocument_donotparse.docx
```

So basically `File.separator` gets translated to `%5c`

Now this is the code I am using:

```java
    public void uploadFiles(@NotNull List<String> filenames, By input, By progressBar, FileType fileType) {
        log.trace("Uploading files: {}", filenames);
        getExistingElement(input).sendKeys(Utils.parseFilenamesForMultipleUpload(filenames));
        throwIfParsingFailed(fileType);
        waitForAllElementsToDisappear(progressBar);
    }
```

and since I also need to upload multiple files at once, I need the util function:

```java
    public String parseFilenamesForMultipleUpload(@NotNull Collection<String> filenames) {
        return String.join(" \n ", filenames
                .stream()
                .map(filename -> new File(Objects.requireNonNull(
                        Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResource(filename)).getFile()).getAbsolutePath())
                .toList());
    }
```

The only thing that worked so far was basically changing code to use "normal" backslashes:

```java
String DOCX = "uploads/mock/document_donotparse.docx";
```

I would, however, like to use `File.separator` back again.

Also I am having no problems at all when reading `json` or `properties` files, for which paths are also separated with `File.separator`, so the problem must lie somewhere with the upload code.

Comment: Before `.toList()` in parseFilenamesForMultipleUpload, try to put `.peek(System.out::println)` and check if the mapping is substituting `%5c` in the returned string.

Comment: *The only thing that worked so far was basically changing code to use "normal" backslashes:*. Those are *not* backslashes. They are *forward* slashes. Perhaps your software is expecting a URL not a file path? That would account for why your Windows file separators are getting escaped

Comment: @hiren yes, parseFilenamesForMultipleUpload seems to be percenting the string...

Comment: Irrespective of whether it's a URL or a file path just use forward slashes for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@hiren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9192223/hiren) I pinpointed that the place where parsing to `%5c` occured was `parseFilenamesForMultipleUpload`. So I added `URLDecoder` to get rid of percentages and created my own method `removePath` to remove path part of file regardless of type of file separator.

Here is the the code:

`parseFilenamesForMultipleUpload` is very similiar I just added more mappings to make it cleaner and added mapping through `decodeQuery` method, which simply translates percentages.

```java
    public String parseFilenamesForMultipleUpload(@NotNull Collection<String> filenames) {
        return filenames
                .stream()
                .map(Utils::getFile)
                .map(File::getPath)
                .map(Utils::decodeQuery)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }
```

`Utils#getFile` is simply some code from previous version of `parseFilenamesForMultipleUpload` method extracted fo clarity:

```java
    @Contract("_ -> new")
    private @NotNull File getFile(String filename) {
        return new File(Objects.requireNonNull(Utils.class.getClassLoader().getResource(filename)).getFile());
    }
```

I then map it again with `File#getPath` instead of `File#AbsolutePath` like before, and finally `decodeQuery` translates percentage style.

`Utils#decodeQuery`:

```java
    public String decodeQuery(String query) {
        return URLDecoder.decode(query, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
```

And finally I join them with a newline character.

Then, to be able to extract filename from filepath I created such method:

```java
    public String removePath(@NotNull String filepath) {
        for (char c : new char[]{'/', '\\', File.separatorChar, File.pathSeparatorChar}) {
            filepath = cutFilePath(filepath, c);
        }
        return filepath;
    }
```

where `cutFilePath` is:

```java
    private @NotNull String cutFilePath(@NotNull String filepath, char delimiter) {
        int charIndex = filepath.lastIndexOf(delimiter);
        return charIndex > -1 ? filepath.substring(charIndex + 1) : filepath;
    }
```

Everything is working :)